# It is possible in regex to take new line inputs only?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my regex right now:

```
/([0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2})?)/gm
```

and it takes inputs like this:

```
123456 or 12345678
```

But if i wrote it like this:

```
1234567812345678
```

it gives a match.
It is a way to prevent that?

the language is javascript

Comment: If you have the numbers in a larger string, use `\b[0-9]{6}(?:[0-9]{2})?\b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of your global flag, for get ride of this problem you can use start and end anchors :

```
^([0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2})?)$
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/nZ9iB0/1

Also as a more elegant way you can concise you regex and use following :

```
^([0-9]{6}([0-9]{2})?)$
```

Comment: Or even shorter but not so elegant `^\d{6}(\d\d)?$`

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `^` and `$` anchors worked for me: `^([0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2})?)$`.

```
m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```

Example available [here](https://regex101.com/r/iY7iJ6/3).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `m` flag if you aren't using `^` or `$`

As for your question, yes, it is. You are looking for boundaries, if you want the number to be anywhere but not together with other characters - `\b([0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}(?:[0-9]{2})?)\b`, as seen https://regex101.com/r/hO1pH4/1

If you want it to match only if it's the only "word" in line, you can use anchors `^` and `$`, like other answers suggest (in which case you need `m` flag)

By the way, there's no reason to repeat `[0-9]{2}` three times, might as well use `\b([0-9]{6}(?:[0-9]{2})?)\b`